# Data Issue with spice refresh in quicksight

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight, quicksight-embedding

I am using spice refresh in my quicksigh reports and observed that spice is sometimes importing the data and sometimes not. ( The data is present in the query every-time. ) The schedule history is as below :

> Date Started (UTC)      Status     Information
> Job Type
>
> 2020/07/01 04:46:00    Completed   Ingestion completed in 4 minutes 11
> seconds. Rows dropped: 0, Rows ingested: 1780995.   Manual, Full
> refresh
>
> 2020/07/01 02:15:40   Completed     Ingestion completed in 1 minutes 56
> seconds. Rows dropped: 0, Rows ingested: 0        Scheduled, Full
> refresh
>
> 2020/06/30 06:43:08   Completed      Ingestion completed in 3 minutes 51
> seconds.Rows dropped: 0, Rows ingested: 1780944.  Manual, Full refresh
>
> 2020/06/30 06:15:32   Completed      Ingestion completed in 2 minutes 1
> seconds. Rows dropped: 0, Rows ingested: 0         Scheduled, Full
> refresh
>
> 2020/06/30 05:15:32   Completed      Ingestion completed in 3 minutes 56
> seconds. Rows dropped: 0, Rows ingested: 1780944    Scheduled, Full
> refresh
>
> 2020/06/30 04:15:32   Completed      Ingestion completed in 1 minutes 58
> seconds. Rows dropped: 0, Rows ingested: 0          Scheduled, Full
> refresh

Regardless of whether it's a manual or scheduled run, the data is not importing sometimes. The query runs on the top of Athena.